# How do I apply font-family and size to multiple dynamic DIVs individually upon selection using jQuery, CSS and HTML?

Tags: jquery, html, dynamic

I am using a solution I found in stackoverflow.com to apply font family and size to few dynamic DIVs. But it's applying the font-family and size on clicking of mouse after I selected desired font and size. But I want that should happen only to the selected DIV and I want to select the text in DIV first and then apply font and size. not the reverse way. Can you help me? Below is the code:

```
<form id="myform">
    <button>erase</button>
    <select id="fs"> 
        <option value="Arial">Arial</option>
        <option value="Verdana ">Verdana </option>
        <option value="Impact ">Impact </option>
        <option value="Comic Sans MS">Comic Sans MS</option>
    </select>
    <select id="size">
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="30">30</option>
    </select>
</form>
<br />
<div id="container" class="changeMe">
    <div id="float">
        <p>
            Text into container
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#fs").change(function() {
    //alert($(this).val());
    $('.changeMe').css("font-family", $(this).val());
});

$("#size").change(function() {
    $('.changeMe').css("font-size", $(this).val() + "px");
});
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to do, do you want the text in the div to change to the selected values in the dropdown only when you click on the text?

Comment: Hm, you are creating a HTML editor, right?

Comment: Yes. I am creating a HTML editor Mr. Lister.

Comment: @ KirKill - Yes I want the text in DIV (multiple DIVs) to change to the selected values in the dropdown only when I select a particular DIV. Now values are applying to all DIVs. But I need it apply to individually on selection.

Answer (score 0):

You were on the good path, the problem was that with your Jquery you were actually saying: "When one of the drop-down is changed, modify the css of all the elements with the "changeMe" class". I think the thing you actually want is something like: "When a paragraph in the div container is clicked, change the css of the clicked paragraph".

I made a jsfiddle for you, it does what you want, http://jsfiddle.net/QdfmZ/

```
$("#container").on('click','p',function(){
  $(this).css("font-size", $("#size").val() + "px");
  $(this).css("font-family", $("#fs").val());
});
```

This is the Jquery, first we tell that the div with the id "container" needs to listen to all clicks on the "p" elements. After that it is pretty simple, $(this) represents the clicked paragraph so we change his css with the values of the drop downs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer KirKill. your answer is good. But instead of clicking on the text first we need to select the text then we need to select font-size in drop-down then only that font-size or font-family should change.

Comment: Hi KirKill, your code working outside of my editor. But it's not working when i include it in my editor code. Can you help me?